# How to stop box shadows from mixing with each other?

Tags: html, css

I have a site with for divs in the middle, where each one is represented by a box with a box-shadow. The problem is, that the colors of the 4 shadows are mixing with each other.
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```css
.text1{
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.text2{
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 150px 20px rgb(0, 130, 255, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0,130,255,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 130, 255, 0.7);
}

.text3{
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0,255,0,0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0,255,0,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0,255,0,0.7);
}

.text4{
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
}
```

and here the HTML:

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="game text1"><a href="#">text</a></div>
        <div class="game text2">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="game text3">text</div>
        <div class="game text4">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all you are using partially transparent colors which cause part of the 'blending'. Secondly, the box shadow mechanism uses the *blur radius* (`150px`) and *spread* (`20px`) to smear and blend the shadows width their own background and those of surrounding elements. As the distance between the buttons is less than `2 * 150px` the shadows overlap and blend together. The order of the buttons in the document determines *how* the overlap takes place (first to last).

Comment: @RenevanderLende Thank you for your answer and I know that, I just wanted to know if there was a way to "disable" that, because I want to keep the blur, spread and alpha as I have them there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are on top of each other because of their `z-index` so one of them is less and goes under the other's box shadow with higher z-index (not z-index but latter rectangle is on top of other)

you can use pseudo element and give the box shadows to it then set their z-index to `-1` so they go under all rectangles:

```css
.text1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.text2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

.text3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

.text4 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.text1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgb(0, 130, 255, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 130, 255, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 130, 255, 0.7);
}

.text3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7);
}

.text4::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px 20px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
}
```